# Visual Composer where to edit CSS - Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, visual-composer

I'm editing a customized wordpress theme that has visual composer installed in it. I can edit a lot of css in the default editor from Wordpress. But there are some css tags such as: .vc_custom_1496470898482 that I don't know where to edit.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you could not edit the css in visual composer.But you can assign id for the selected row or column  and write your own css

Comment: Hi Ravi, thanks for your answer. This is what I've been doing but since the tag that I want to overwrite already has !important behind it I can't overwrite again with my own css file. Do you know where to locate the current css?

Comment: Have you tried adding your own `!important` tag to overwrite it? Have a look at the [Cascading and Specificity Stack Overflow Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/450/cascading-and-specificity/2253/calculating-selector-specificity#t=201707191337543181956)

Answer (score 2):

This is an auto generated CSS by visual composer so can't be edited.

So there are two approaches for applying your CSS to it and these are as follows:

1. Inside visual composer, add your own `class/id` for that particular row/element and then apply CSS using this newly added `class/id`. (Recommended)
2. Override this class with same name i.e `.vc_custom_1496470898482` in your CSS file or inside [custom CSS editor](https://wpbakery.atlassian.net/wiki/display/VC/Custom+CSS) provided by the visual composer or theme.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Broken link in #2